# java arraylist how to sort Int value that mixed with string

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

my arraylist :

```
"LVL:100 MONEY:1489 MANA: 42,1",
"LVL:67 MONEY:389 MANA: 33,5",
"LVL:47 MONEY:4229 MANA: 59,7",
"LVL:120 MONEY:1189 MANA: 94,5",
"LVL:150 MONEY:189 MANA: 19,2",
```

so I want it to sorted by value of MONEY

```
"LVL:47 MONEY:4229 MANA: 59,7",
"LVL:100 MONEY:1489 MANA: 42,1",
"LVL:120 MONEY:1189 MANA: 94,5",
"LVL:67 MONEY:389 MANA: 33,5",
"LVL:150 MONEY:189 MANA: 19,2",
```

Comment: what is  the structure of your object , it is List<SomeObject> , what is that object ?

Comment: its list of String ArrayList<String> playerstats = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: please share your main method and how you are populating the values in the playerstats.

Comment: maybe I should use json,but I dont know how to assign the child of the value

Comment: I get the value from a jsonObject from url string 
playerstats = rootobj.get("stats").getAsJsonObject(); 
LVL= playerstats.get("lvl").getAsInt()
MONEY= playerstats.get("money").getAsInt()
MANA= playerstats.get("mana").getAsInt()

then return it as string "LVL:" + LVL + " MONEY:"+MONEY + " MANA:"+MANA <-- added to arraylist

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  If you have the data as JSON, you should be able to sort the JSON objects by the value of money, then output the sorted list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my attempt using Streams API. I make a new Comparator to give to sorted method in order to sort the money based on where it appears in the string.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SortMoney {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> playerstats = Arrays.asList("LVL:100 MONEY:1489 MANA: 42,1",
                                             "LVL:67 MONEY:389 MANA: 33,5",
                                             "LVL:47 MONEY:4229 MANA: 59,7",
                                             "LVL:120 MONEY:1189 MANA: 94,5",
                                             "LVL:150 MONEY:189 MANA: 19,2");

    List<String> sortedPlayerStates = playerstats.stream()
                                                 .map(data -> data.split(":"))
                                                 .sorted((o1, o2) -> {
                                                     int a = Integer.parseInt(o1[2].split(" ")[0]);
                                                     int b = Integer.parseInt(o2[2].split(" ")[0]);
                                                     if (a > b) {
                                                     return -1;
                                                     } else if (b > a) {
                                                     return 1;
                                                     } else {
                                                     return 0;
                                                     }

                                                 })
                                                 .map(data -> String.join(":", data))
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

    sortedPlayerStates.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Output:
[image]

Let me know if this is the result you want.

**Edit:** changed the code to store in variable in case you want to manipulate it later.